# Sonar runner exit with Null Pointer Exception on a multi module project (one in C#, the other in JavaScript)

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to configure a multi module project in sonar to cover all the sides of our application (mainly the C# and JavaScript parts)

If I'm running it on the C# part alone (not using the multi module architecture), it works just fine. If i run different modules, it breaks.

I chose to split the configuration between the different module. (And putting everything configuration in the same file gives the same result)

Below, the 3 configuration.

The main one:

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=XXXXX
sonar.projectVersion=XXXXX
sonar.projectName=XXXXXX

# Info required for Sonar 
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=.
sonar.modules = csharp, javascript

# C#
csharp.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/to/slnFolder

# JS
javascript.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/to/js/files
```

The one used for C#

```
# C#
sonar.projectName=XXXX CS
sonar.language=cs

#Core C# Settings 
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=MyProject.sln
sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true
sonar.dotnet.version=3.5

#Gendarme
sonar.gendarme.mode=  
# Gallio 
sonar.gallio.mode= skip
# FXCop 
sonar.fxcop.mode=
#StyleCop 
sonar.stylecop.mode=
#NDeps
sonar.ndeps.mode=skip
```

And the javascript one:

```
# JS
sonar.projectName=3DSaphi JS
sonar.language=js
```

The exception I end up having (and that seems linked to the dotnet module):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: java.lang.NullPoint
erException
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.sensor.AbstractRegularDotNetSensor.assem
bliesFound(AbstractRegularDotNetSensor.java:90)
        at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.sensor.AbstractRegularDotNetSensor.shoul
dExecuteOnProject(AbstractRegularDotNetSensor.java:72)
        at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.sensor.AbstractRuleBasedDotNetSensor.sho
uldExecuteOnProject(AbstractRuleBasedDotNetSensor.java:51)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.BatchExtensionDictionnary.shouldKeep(BatchExtensi
onDictionnary.java:109)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.BatchExtensionDictionnary.getFilteredExtensions(B
atchExtensionDictionnary.java:99)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.BatchExtensionDictionnary.select(BatchExtensionDi
ctionnary.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:5
7)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:97)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:12
8)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:114)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:109)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:104)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.jav
a:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
        at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:6
9)
        at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
        ... 3 more
```

So my questions are:

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
If yes, any idea of what I could do to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope i didn't. I just went with a different approach.  Running one instance of sonar for the C# and one for the JS. Not a beauty, but it made the job.

Comment: Module too manage différent langages in the same run is new. What is the version of sonar are you using ?

I see the module is available on sonarqube 5.0

Comment: It was the most recent version at the time (which i believe was 3.3).
The feature was just introduced back then (see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2602 ).

Comment: Module too manage différent langages in the same run is new. What is the version of sonar are you using ?

I see the module is available on sonarqube 5.0